# Como puedo convertir un string a int para asignarle un valor de ASCII en C?

Tags: c

Antes que nada, soy nuevo en esto, agradeceré su apoyo y explicaciones. Estoy resolviendo un problema de CS50 en el cual tengo que realizar un programa que simule un Scrabble, en el cual estamos usando un array para asignarle un valor a cada letra del alfabeto. El programa pide una palabra para player 1 y otra para player 2, después se comparan las palabras y se muestra el jugador ganador. ¿Cómo puedo convertir las palabras y separarlas para que se asigne el valor?
Agradecería sus explicaciones pero no quiero un código que me resuelva el problema sin que lo comprenda.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es formar palabras con caracteres y poder separar dichos caracteres (letras), te recomiendo crear un array de caracteres. Las variables tipo `char` son caracteres de 8bits, que son fácilmente asignables con valores ASCII para obtener tus letras. Para definir: `char palabra[100]`, en este caso tienes una palabra de máximo 100 caracteres, incluidos los espacios (por lo que también puede ser una frase). Cuando tenga estos arrays definidos les puedes asignar valor mediante un bucle `for` mediante `scanf("%c", &palabra[i])`, siendo `i` el contador del bucle.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

> Como puedo convertir un string a int para asignarle un valor de ASCII en C?

No puedes.

---

Toda esa pregunta no tiene sentido:

- Puedes convertir cadenas (*string*) a entero (`int`) cuando la cadena representa un entero.
- No puedes asignar un valor a una conversión ¿Qué sentido tiene convertir la cadena *"123"* en `123` para asignarle otro valor?.
- El código ASCII correlaciona una letra con un valor numérico, así que no puede reemplazar a una cadena.

> estamos usando un array para asignarle un valor a cada letra del alfabeto

No necesitas hacer nada de eso, cada letra ya tiene un valor: su valor ASCII:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]